# How to Generate DDL Scripts(schema, table, MS_Description only) by mssql-scripter?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, mssql-scripter

As the title suggests, I would like to generate DDL scripts that include only the schema, table, and MS_Description.

So, how can I adjust my current syntax to achieve this?

(I am using a Mac system and cannot generate the scripts by SSMS software.)

```
mssql-scripter -S {host} \                                                                                          
  --exclude-use-database \     
  --display-progress \
  -d {database}  \         
  -U {username} \
  -P {password} \
  -f ./example.sql
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation? https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-scripter/blob/dev/doc/usage_guide.md

Comment: also, i don't know what MS_Description is

Comment: @siggemannen, I think `MS_Description` is the name of an extended property.